# Parsing Nested JSON and Manipulating It in Ruby

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

This is my first attempt at parsing nested JSON with Ruby. I need to go through the JSON to pull out specific values for "_id", "name", and "type" for instance. I then need to create a reference table so that I can refer to each "_id" and associated information. I also need to combine information from multiple JSON responses. I've been able to get basic information and have tried a few things I've found online. I just need a little assistance with a starting point. If anyone has any ideas of where to start with this I'd really appreciate it.

Devices JSON response hash. Each device starts with _id.

```
{
"api": "1.0",
"error": null,
"id": "60b5d4c3077862123cfa4443",
"result": {
    "devices": [
        {
            "_id": "123456787786211fd31f3dd",
            "batteryPowered": true,
            "category": "door_lock",
            "deviceTypeId": "144_1_1",
            "firmware": [
                {
                    "id": "us.144.1_1.0",
                    "version": "2.6"
                }
            ],
            "gatewayId": "1234567807786214fbc6bd4e",
            "info": {
                "firmware.stack": "3.28",
                "hardware": "0",
                "manufacturer": "Kwikset",
                "model": "912",
                "protocol": "zwave",
                "zwave.node": "2",
                "zwave.smartstart": "no"
            },
            "name": "Garage Door",
            "parentDeviceId": "",
            "persistent": false,
            "reachable": false,
            "ready": true,
            "roomId": "1234567807786211fd31f3eb",
            "security": "middle",
            "status": "idle",
            "subcategory": "",
            "type": "doorlock"
        },
        {
            "_id": "1234567897786211fd31f3ed",
            "batteryPowered": true,
            "category": "door_lock",
            "deviceTypeId": "59_1_1129",
            "firmware": [
                {
                    "id": "us.59.18064.0",
                    "version": "3.3"
                },
                {
                    "id": "us.59.18065.1",
                    "version": "11.0"
                }
            ],
            "gatewayId": "1234567897786214fbc6bd4e",
            "info": {
                "firmware.stack": "6.3",
                "hardware": "3",
                "manufacturer": "Schlage",
                "model": "BE469ZP",
                "protocol": "zwave",
                "zwave.node": "3",
                "zwave.smartstart": "no"
            },
            "name": "Front Door",
            "parentDeviceId": "",
            "persistent": false,
            "reachable": true,
            "ready": true,
            "roomId": "1234567807786211fd31f3ec",
            "security": "high",
            "status": "idle",
            "subcategory": "",
            "type": "doorlock"
        },
        {
            "_id": "1234567897786211fd31f40a",
            "batteryPowered": false,
            "category": "switch",
            "deviceTypeId": "57_20562_12344",
            "firmware": [
                {
                    "id": "us.57.29240.0",
                    "version": "5.25"
                }
            ],
            "gatewayId": "1234567807786214fbc6bd4e",
            "info": {
                "firmware.stack": "4.54",
                "hardware": "255",
                "manufacturer": "Honeywell",
                "model": "ZW4103/39337",
                "protocol": "zwave",
                "zwave.node": "4",
                "zwave.smartstart": "no"
            },
            "name": "Lamp Switch",
            "parentDeviceId": "",
            "persistent": false,
            "reachable": true,
            "ready": true,
            "roomId": "1234567807786211fd31f416",
            "security": "no",
            "status": "idle",
            "subcategory": "interior_plugin",
            "type": "switch.outlet"
        },
        {
            "_id": "1234567b07786211fd31f40e",
            "batteryPowered": false,
            "category": "dimmable_light",
            "deviceTypeId": "57_20548_12339",
            "firmware": [
                {
                    "id": "us.57.29747.0",
                    "version": "5.21"
                }
            ],
            "gatewayId": "1234567d07786214fbc6bd4e",
            "info": {
                "firmware.stack": "4.34",
                "hardware": "255",
                "manufacturer": "Honeywell",
                "model": "39339/ZW3107",
                "protocol": "zwave",
                "zwave.node": "5",
                "zwave.smartstart": "no"
            },
            "name": "Lamp Dimmer",
            "parentDeviceId": "",
            "persistent": false,
            "reachable": true,
            "ready": true,
            "roomId": "1234567807786211fd31f416",
            "security": "no",
            "status": "idle",
            "subcategory": "dimmable_plugged",
            "type": "dimmer.outlet"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

There is then also a JSON response that lists the functions for each device in the same format above. However instead of "devices"=> it is "items"=> and the beach function is the _id key again.

I'd like to combine function _id tags and descriptions with the device JSON, so  I can create a way to send my script "unlock door lock 1" and it subs the number with the _id of the device and the function _id.

Comment: It'd be easier to see what's going on here by breaking that out over multiple lines, but where is this `"_id"` field?

Comment: Thanks tadman. I reformatted the JSON so it's easier to read. I each JSON response it contains _id keys for items that can be referenced for a particular device and then function. So the above JSON is the device response where it reports each device. The function JSON Response has _id keys for each function to reference. So if I want to lock a door, I need to reference the 24 character ID for that particular lock's lock function. So I want to put the fields that I need into a separate array or formatted JSON that I can send back to the control system.

Comment: Does "door lock 1" refer to `data['result']['devices'][0]`?

Comment: JSON is an *interchange* format, not a SQL database. The best solution is to parse out your data into a real database, and then perform queries. While you could do it as JSON, you clearly have a data inventory here; why not treat it properly?

Comment: If you insist on doing it as JSON anyway, consider [pattern matching](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/doc/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with a very rough navigator function like this:

```rb
def find_device(data, name, index)
  # Filter through the device list...
  data['result']['devices'].select do |device|
    # ...for matching names.
    device.name == name
  end[index] # Take indexed entry
end
```

Where now you can do `find_device(data, 'door_lock', 0)` to dig up that entry.

Converting `"door lock 1"` to `[ 'door_lock', 0 ]` should be pretty trivial:

```rb
def to_location(str)
  # Split off the name component(s) and index number
  *name, index = str.split(/\s+/)

  # Reassemble with underscores and -1 to account for 0-index
  [ name.join('_'), index.to_i - 1 ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks tadman. I'll give this a go when I get home from a service call. My objective I think is to either create an array in memory or write out to a flat file the information the script will need to reference. The door number is actually the _id. So, if I send a command for door 1, I'll need it to reference Door ID 123456787786211fd31f3dd and a similar function ID pulled from another JSON request in the lock or unlock command.

Comment: I'm not sure how you map 1 to 1234...dd but sure.